# If you have driven with excessive oil for a few days, then removed it, how do you know if there has been damage and to what extent?

Tags: oil-change

MechAnic filled engine oil way above maximum and I have driven for a few days and only just realized now because I was getting a burning smell and checked the oil
Level.  I knew the rocker The valve gasket had been leaking from much earlier but it was a small leak and was told not to worry about it.  However coinciding with this oil change followed by burning smell it seems to have leaked heavily and dipstick seems to be 1.5 litres above the maximum mark.

Since it has been a few days of driving am I likely to get lucky with no engine damage so long as I drain the excess oil now?

I read things like spark plugs may be foiled as a result so perhaps I should check those.

What other symptoms should I look for to know if there had been general or engine damage?

Thanks

Comment: Open ended questions asking for speculation/opinions are not on topic for SE sites; please return when said engine is making an unusual noise :)

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate to know what symptoms to look for over mistake in repair and maintenance

Comment: That stackexchange network is not intended to be used for questions that are answered with lists, such as "tell me 100 uses for an old sock" or "what are the top ten problems that low tire pressure may cause?" - it is focused on things that are actually concretely a problem right now. If/when your car develops a problem, come and tell us the facts so that we may help diagnose the cause. Questions of the ilk "I did X which might cause something, but what?" are not on topic

Comment: @CaiusJard, I personally don't see anything wrong with asking a question which requires a list for the answer. I think some will be valid, some won't - necessarily based solely on the type of answer.  But I also never read the rules here. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't hydrolocked and nothing is leaking - then there's likely no damage.

Comment: The valve gasket is leaking and I have been smelling burning oil.

Comment: Update the question with this information then.

Comment: @JamesWilson, sounds like a separate issue. Don't think valve cover gasket would blow because of excess oil - there just wouldn't be enough pressure unless you filled your engine with oil from top to bottom (at which point you'd have multiple other issues).